# Message box position

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a vba file and everything is working properly. However, ive run the codes again and noticed the message box does not appear in the center.
How can i make the message box appear in the center of excel again?

Comment: Who made the change? Codes or just mouse dragging or anything else?

Comment: do you have multiple screens?

Comment: Codes have not been changed. But the message box keeps appearing in the lower right corner of excel.not on the very corner thou. I just want to know if theres a code that i can reposition the message box to appear in the center again.